# how export List of all VMs ( VMs network VLANs id ) in Cluster from Vcenter?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

How can I export List of all VMs ( VMs network VLANs id ) in Cluster from Vcenter ? I don't see there any network details option.

Using Vcenter 6.5

[image]

I tried this option. I only replaced `Get-VirtualPortGroup` to `Get-VDPortgroup`, but not works for me, got some erros

```
$Portgroups = Get-VDPortgroup |Sort-Object -Unique
$Datastores = Get-Datastore |Sort-Object -Unique
$VMs = get-vm 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Output = @()
foreach ($currentVM in $VMs) {
    $VM = New-Object -TypeName PsObject
    $VM | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $currentVM.Name
    foreach ($Portgroup in $Portgroups) {
        $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Portgroup.Name -Value (($currentVM|Get-VDPortgroup).name -contains $Portgroup.Name)
    }
    foreach ($Datastore in $Datastores) {
        $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Datastore.Name -Value (($currentVM|Get-Datastore).name -contains $Datastore.Name)
    }
    $Output += $VM
}
$Output |Export-Csv -Path "vm_export.csv"
```

error:

```
Get-VDPortgroup : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:9 char:93
+ ... rty -Name $Portgroup.Name -Value (($currentVM|Get-VDPortgroup).name - ...
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (test-vm:PSObject) [Get-VDPortgroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Commands.Cmdlets.GetVDPortgroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get every information you need via PowerCLI.

```perl
Get-Cluster cluster |
    Get-vm |Get-NetworkAdapter |
    Select Parent,NetworkName,@{name='VlanID';e={(Get-VirtualPortgroup -Name $_.NetworkName |select -First 1).vlanid}} |
    Export-Csv -Path "vm_export.csv"
```

---

Getting all portgroups and datastores as separate columns makes it a little more complicated. This works for me:

```perl
$Portgroups = Get-VirtualPortGroup |Sort-Object -Unique
$Datastores = Get-Datastore |Sort-Object -Unique
$VMs = get-vm
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Output = @()
foreach ($currentVM in $VMs) {
    $VM = New-Object -TypeName PsObject
    $VM | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $currentVM.Name
    foreach ($Portgroup in $Portgroups) {
        $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Portgroup.Name -Value (($currentVM|Get-VirtualPortGroup).name -contains $Portgroup.Name)
    }
    foreach ($Datastore in $Datastores) {
        $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Datastore.Name -Value (($currentVM|Get-Datastore).name -contains $Datastore.Name)
    }
    $Output += $VM
}
$Output |Export-Csv -Path "vm_export.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if VM has two NICs, how will be then ? Or how to add also used datastores ?

Comment: In my example you will get a line for every NIC. A VM with three NICs will show up three times. For datastores you can replace Get-NetworkAdapter with Get-Datastore (and use the appropiate properties). To get both in the same line it gets more complicated.

Comment: Aah, you have right, is showing per line. is possible to show it per column ? NIC1, NIC2
Then how please also add e.g. datastores ?  so then I can create my own export.
Thanks

Comment: I added an extended example that produces a matrix that has columns for all portgroups and datastores and shows which are connected to wich VM.

Comment: thanks Gerald, btw do you know  why is VM names truncated to 18 characters from basic get-vm command ? how to get full name ?
get-vm>
This-is-my-test-ma... PoweredOn  2        4.000

Comment: You should ask separate questions for this.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use [rvtool](https://www.robware.net/rvtools/). Just install it on your computer and save an excel report. Then you can filter as you want.